# Autotest for nodejs on linux

Tags: node.js, tdd, mocha.js

I would like my Mocha tests to run when I save. I have been searching for an autotest-like module for node with no luck so far. I did see a post that described how to set up a file watcher on a Mac using Ruby, but I wonder if there is might be something native to node?

Comment: Doesn't mocha support this out-of-the-box with the `--watch` switch? It's in the [docs](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/)

Comment: yup mocha supports it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

file watcher exist but is not so reliable on Node.JS, still a lot changing & sometimes unstable (i reach some error results sometines), and (the most problematic) does not have the same behaviour regarding the OS you are running...

But if you still really want to :
http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener

and a better approach :
https://github.com/coolaj86/node-inotify-plusplus